# Can't smooth my retopology correctly

Tags: modeling, sculpting, topology

My second attempt to make a retopology and it's killing my nerves again.

[image: retopology]

smoothing vertices

[image: trying to smooth]

result

[image: wtf]

also tried to recalculate normals
[image: recalculating]

same problem
[image: didn't help]

Please send help, i don't know how to continue studying uv, texturing etc.

Comment: Inner (not visible) geometry, duplicates or inverted normals? In edit mode, try to select all and Ctrl+Shift+N (for the normals)

Comment: Same problem. Maybe i don't understand how recalculating works?

Comment: Could you upload it so that we can have a look? Please use this link to do it: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: out of curiosity, why not just add a SubSurf modifier at the end of the stack?

Comment: ...just noticed that there is a shrinkwrap modifier... so smoothing may work but at the end vertices will be shrinked

Comment: What do you mean by smoothing your topology? If you mean smooth shading you need to select your object in Object mode then press w > Shade Smooth... the Smooth Vertex tool change the mesh itself, not its shading (a bit confusing by the way)

Comment: So, i tried subsurf and it's pretty good. I just thought that subsurf will make no sense cause it's creating more faces or smth so retopology will be useless.

Comment: and also, yes, you have a Shrinkwrap, so as long as you don't apply it your mesh will stick to its target and the Smooth Vertex won't work (if that's what you want)

Comment: thanks for such activity, so can u tell the best way to smooth my retopo for future unwrapping and etc. Is it better just to add subsurf or smth else?

Comment: Remove or disable or apply the shrinkwrap to see your 'real' result. Then you'll be able to smooth or use subsurf if you want (subsurf will effectively add more geom but this is matter of choice at some point).

Comment: An option can also be to add a smooth modifier at the end.

Comment: For retopo you need to use some key edge loops, for eg. eyes edge loops, nose, lips.
I stongly sugest to take a look over this tutorial. [edge loops tutorial for beginers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Moe7tWbyUBw) Unfortunatly i think you need to recrate the retopoloy to obtain the correct shape of the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

So, finally i just applied subdivision surface, removed the shrinkwrap and got the result. Still don't understand the problem with smoothing vertices tab, but i have my retopologized guy already!///. Thanks for such a quick feedback! Love you Blender!

[image]

Yaaaaaay!
[image]

Comment: Smooth Vertex is a tool to change the topology, it makes the angles between the faces softer, it's not like the Shade Smooth option which allows you to simulate a smoother appearance of the object and won't change its topology in any way

Comment: To add to what @moonboots said, smooth vertex will distort any non manifold edges